# How can you add typing to a python class programmatically based on a dict?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a dict specifying various argparse parameters that can be provided to a function and I want to add typing to the args parameters being taken by the function. Is there someway to get the typing from the argparse parameter dict field ["config"]["type"]?

How I'm doing it now is specifying the typing in two different places like so:

```
argparse_args = [
  {
    name: "some_arg",
    config: {
      "type": int,
      "help": "This is some arg"
    }
  }
]

class Args():
  some_arg: int

def someFunc(args: Args):
  continue
```

This works but I have to duplicate the typing which is worrisome because it could lead to me making mistakes where I forget to add or remove typing in one of the places.

Is there some way for the class `Args` to get the typing from `argparse_args` programmatically or some other way to pass the typing to `someFunc`? E.g. something like this:

```
class Args():
  for arg in argparse_args:
    self[arg["name"]]: arg["config"]["type"]
```

I know that syntactically doesn't make sense but I'm not sure how else to express what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: In a sense, that defeats the purpose.  Remember, you don't actually have to declare `some_arg` at ALL in the declaration of `Args`.  You're just doing it for commentary purposes, and in that case, the commentary should include the exact type you are expecting.

Comment: Type hints are for *static* type checking; you need the hints *before* your code runs to instantiate `Args`.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with these type hints?

Comment: Technically you _could_ dynamically construct your class' [`__annotations__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-48) dictionary of course. But this will be completely opaque to any static type checker. This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is your actual goal here? Do you want your IDE to give you insights about the attributes of the `args` object in your function? That is not going to happen, if you _dynamically_ create annoations.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm trying to not duplicate the type declarations. I have to specify them for argparse and I have to specify them if I want type hinting for the function. I can't figure how to do both in a way that doesn't duplicate the specifications though.

Comment: @AlexLong you aren't understanding my question **why do you want type hints**? Typically, these are merely just hints. Specifying them dynamicalyl doesn't help anyone reading your code. Furthermore, there are third-party static analysis tools, like `mypy`, `pyright` etc that can do static type checking, but again, that won't be able to make use of *annotations added at runtime*